# How to add authorization with per-item based permissions to REST API endpoints in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

My API assumes collections called Storages, which hold Items - those Items can be added, edited or removed from Storage. One user can be a member of more than one Storage, and could have one of three possible roles in given storage - Editor, Commentator and Viewer.
I have already implemented authentication through JWT - now I need ot add authorization, so certain actions can be performed only by members of specific Storage with proper roles - for example, adding items should be only possible for Editors. At first I thought of the most straightforward way - that is, creating custom policy and adding proper attributes to the endpoints:

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddAuthorization
(
    options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy
        (
            "StorageEditor",
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("StorageEditor", "{storageId}") // I need to know the id of storage request is associated with
        );
    }
);
```

*ItemsController.cs*

```
// Id of storage in question is part of the route
[HttpPost("storages/{storageId}/items")]
[Authorize(Policy = "StorageEditor")
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateItem(
    [FromRoute(Name = "storageID")] int storageId)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

However, I need to know the id of Storage user is attempting to modify in order to decide whether or not he should be allowed to do so - and as such, it cannot be hardcoded inside *Authorize* attribute or policy based on Claims.
Obviously, I can simply check for that inside the method itself - after all, it will have all the information required in order to perform this authorization. However, this way adds a lot of boilerplate code to each of these methods, which I think is not ideal.

Is there some cleaner way of implementing such authorization than just throwing this logic into the endpoint method?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi** , Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core , you can add role by yourself In JWT method and use these roles in action directly

**In JWT method:**

```
// Add roles as multiple claims
foreach(var role in user.Roles) 
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
    
    // these also work - and reduce token size
    // claims.Add(new Claim("roles", role.Name));
    // claims.Add(new Claim("role", role.Name));
}
```

Then you can add `[Authorize(Roles= "xxx")]` to action in controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles= "xxx")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateItem(
    [FromRoute(Name = "storageID")] int storageId)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

If you want to use Policy , you can add Role authorization in Policy.

```
Services.AddAuthorization(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("PolicyName", x =>
    {
        //....any other attribute you want....

        //Add Role authorization
        x.RequireRole("Admin","xx",...);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I needed. I ended up creating custom policies, requirements and handlers - all of this just so that I could inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into them, in order to check if route values match user's roles in given storage. I have tried using standard "Role" claim, but it wasn't enough.

Comment: Hi,you want to add role authorization in custom policies?

Comment: I have edited my answer , you can add different Policy and add role authorization in these Policy according to your needs